# Spring Security 5.2.2 + Spring Boot 2.2 + Oauth Autoconfiguration : Permit some uri and secure only few : 403 Error

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a Authorization Server and Resource Server.
I have auto configured the OAuth default implementation .There was no code required and only the configuration was done in

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri:<auth server configuration url here>
```

Maven Dependencies

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server
            </artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Currently all my urls are getting secured.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/secure/test", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")   
    public @ResponseBody String testService(@RequestBody String name ,@RequestHeader Map<String, String>headers) {
headers.forEach((K,V)->printHeaders(K,V));
}
```

I want my below uri to be accessible to everyone ,

```
@PostMapping(path = "/test", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")  
    public @ResponseBody String testAuthService(@RequestBody String name ,@RequestHeader Map<String, String>headers) {
headers.forEach((K,V)->printHeaders(K,V));
}
```

I tried overriding the below but getting 403 error while trying without a bearer token

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2LoginSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        try {
            http
                .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .mvcMatchers("/api/secure/**").authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Error Response

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-05-07T14:28:22.729+0000",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "path": "/api/test"
}
```

How can I permit only certain urls to be authenticated using Spring Security 5.2.2 + Spring Boot 2.2 + Oauth Autoconfiguration

Comment: welcome to stackoveflow. Take a tour and get your first badge-https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @Deepak was my answer useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a **403** when you do a **POST** you probably have forgotten to provide a **crsrf-token**

CSRF protection is enabled by default in the Java configuration but you can disable it.

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .csrf().disable()                 // <--- disable CSRF 
      .authorizeRequests(...
      ....
```

Or provide a token in your form.

```html
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

If you are using JSON, you can not submit the CSRF token as a parameter.
Instead, submit the token within the header.

```html
<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

JS to attach the header.

```js
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");

$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
});
```